# What is the difference between a Schottky diode and a Shockley diode?

Tags: diodes

I read that the Shockley diode belongs to the family of power devices.

What is the difference between a Schottky diode and a Shockley diode?

Comment: Schottky discovered his surface tunnelling effect 50 yrs before semiconductor diodes were invented. Yet it was about 30 yrs after it was found useful in semiconductor diodes. But even the cat whisker has the Shottky diode effect but is not called that. Nor are any Schokley diodes made

Answer (score 6):

Walter H Schottky was a physicist, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_H._Schottky) He did much work around emission of electrons from surfaces, which led to the metal-semiconductor junction being named after him.

William Schockley was an engineer, mainly at Bell Labs. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation). His work on the junction diode included the Schockley equation, which relates current to an exponential of voltage. $$ I=I_S(e^\frac{V_D}{nV_T}-1)$$

Many people confuse the two. I can't think why.

Comment: There was such a thing as a Shockley diode, it is obsolete. Digikey has 33k hits for Schottky, zero hits for Shockley. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode

Comment: Last sentence is sarcastic, right?

Answer (score 1):

Shockley is two PN junction of semiconductors coupled diode  where as Schottky  diode in metal-semiconductor junction diode. Shockley operates as power, switching device and inorganic solar cell.    Schottky diode is operate as signalling and rectifying device. The barrier is too tiny of schottky diode so, it can operate high frequency or faster response  and low operating power device.